# How can I fetch the ratio in one query?

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, aggregate

I have the following table `values`

```
id | value | team | is_whatever
-------------------------------
 1 |     2 |    1 | true
 2 |     7 |    1 | true
 3 |    10 |    1 | NULL
 4 |     3 |    2 | NULL
 5 |    23 |    2 | true
```

Now I want to fetch the `COUNT()` of rows grouped by `team` and also fetch the ratio where `is_whatever = true`. So the expected result shall be

```
team | count | ratio
--------------------
   1 |     3 | 0.66
   2 |     2 |  0.5
```

My first approach was something like grouping by `team` and then by `is_whatever`. But I wouldn't know how to fetch the `ratio` column:

```
SELECT
    `team`,
    COUNT(*) AS `count`,
    COUNT(`is_whatever`) AS `ratio`
FROM `values`
GROUP BY `team`, `is_whatever`
```

Then I thought about joining the table twice:

```
SELECT
    `v1`.`team`,
    COUNT(`v1`.*) AS `count`,
    COUNT(`v2`.*) AS `ratio`
FROM `values` `v1`
JOIN `values` `v2` ON `v1`.`id` = `v2`.`id`
WHERE `v1`.`is_whatever` = true
GROUP BY `team`
```

But both queries didn't lead me to the desired result. Any idea how I could fetch that in one query?

Comment: If you want a ratio count(is_waht..) / Count(*) surely ???

Comment: Well I want the ratio of `is_whatever = true` in comparison to the total `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
drop table if exists v;
create table v (id integer, value integer, team integer, is_whatever enum('true','false'));
insert into v (id,value,team,is_whatever) values 
('1','2','1','true'),
('2','7','1','true'),
('3','10','1',NULL),
('4','3','2',NULL),
('5','23','2','true');

select team, ct as count, cw/ct as ratio
from
(
select team,count(team) as ct, count(is_whatever) as cw
from v 
group by team
) counts
```

Result:

```
1;3;0.6667
2;2;0.5000
```

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head
You can put an expression in Count

```
Select team, NumberOf as 'Count', NumberOfWhatevers / NumberOf as ratio From
(
  Select team, Count(is_whatever = true) as NumberOfWhatevers,Count(*) as NumberOf 
  From values Group By team
) counts
```